# RRULE, the day before the first wednesday of the month

Tags: icalendar, rrule

All is in the title: I need to create a recurring event on the day (tuesday) before the first wednesday of every month. That tuesday may or may not be in the same month than the wednesday, it just need to be the *yesterday* of the first wednesday of the month.

I tried many ways to express that recurrence but lamentably failed. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at he end of the day I found it:

```
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=TU;BYMONTHDAY=1,2,3,4,5,6,-1
```